# In SQL Dividing a Value by its mean

Tags: sql, mysql, average

I am trying to divide a calculated field (in the example it is called CALC_TIPS) by the mean for that calculated field given a certain COMM_TYPE_ID.  With this query I am able to extract the AVG for each COMM_TYPE_ID.

```
SELECT AVG(CALC_TIPS), COMM_TYPE_ID
FROM (SELECT tips_amount/COMMUNICATIONS_ID AS CALC_TIPS, COMM_TYPE_ID
FROM consumer_action_log) AS cal
GROUP BY COMM_TYPE_ID;
```

How would I then go back and divide each value in the CALC_TIPS field by the average for its COMM_TYPE_ID? I am currently at a loss. Thanks in advance!

Note: I am working with MySQL
Also Note: I know the subquery is not necessary. I am using this query as a proxy for a more complicated query I have to do the same thing with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to join the derived table back to some data on the key COMMS_TYPE_ID.  Not pretty if both outer and inner queries are multi-tabled and large.

```
SELECT tips_amount/COMMUNICATIONS_ID/NULLIF(AVG_TIP,0)
FROM consumer_action_log A   # return to table consumer_action_log
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT AVG(CALC_TIPS) AVG_TIP, COMM_TYPE_ID
    FROM (
        SELECT tips_amount/COMMUNICATIONS_ID AS CALC_TIPS, COMM_TYPE_ID
        FROM consumer_action_log) AS cal
    GROUP BY COMM_TYPE_ID
) B ON A.COMM_TYPE_ID = B.COMM_TYPE_ID
```

The reason for the NULLIF is to turn 0's -> NULL so that you don't get divide by zero errors.

Comment: I am confused as to what exactly OTHERQUERY A represents? What would query A be in my current toy example? The same derived table?

Comment: `How would I then go back and divide each value in the CALC_TIPS field by the average for it's COMM_TYPE_ID?`  It represents whatever you are "going back to"

Answer (score 1):

Two subqueries does it:

```
select cal1.calc_tips/cal2.avgCalc_Tips as theAnswer
  from (Select tips_amount/communication_id as calc_tips
             , comm_type_id
          from consumer_action_log)  cal1
  JOIN (select avg(tips_amount/communication_id) as avgCalcTips
             , comm_type_id
          from consumer_action_log
         group by comm_type_id    
          from consumer_action_log)  cal2
    ON cal1.comm_type_id = cal2.comm_type_id
```

**EDIT:** Assuming of course that communication_id is never zero :)